# jQuery Blur to trigger Click Event

Tags: jquery, click, blur

I would like to trigger an anchor tag being clicked when a text box blurs. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".triggerBlur").blur(function () {
        alert("blurred");
        $(".triggerClick").trigger('click');
        //$(".triggerClick").click(); //also tried this
    });
});
```

Comment: Post also your '.triggerClick' click function

Comment: show your html or provide fiddle

Comment: y are you triggering the same thing..i mean input field

Comment: Triggering click events won't run the native functionality, just the defined handler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve same effect by doing this

if you want to open link in same window use

`window.location = $('.triggerClick').attr('href');`

or if you want to open in new tab use

`window.open($('.triggerClick').attr('href'));`

```
$(".triggerBlur").blur(function () {
    window.open($('.triggerClick').attr('href'));
});
```

Working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/WK3yh/1/)**

Comment: This will open the link in a new tab. Perhaps consider adding a solution for opening in the same window too?

Answer (score 0):

The comments have basically summed this issue up.

Triggering clicks through `.click()` or `.trigger()` will not run native functionality such as following links (thanks @tymeJV). It will only run the handler you attach to it. If you want to follow a link, you would have to use something like this:

```
$(".triggerClick").click(function() {
    var href = $(this).attr("href");
    window.location.href = href;
});
$(".triggerBlur").click(function() {
    $(".triggerClick").trigger("click");
});
```

This would launch the handler, which relocates to the `href` attribute of the link.

Apart from that, you've got it. Both `trigger` and `click` will trigger the click for you.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT:** This solution opens the link in the same window. To open in a new tab, you can use the same code but substitute `window.location.href = href` for `window.open(href)`